# how to set Date value as zero in neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a field startDate. data type is Date. i want to set zero to startdate field. please help with it. thanks in advance.

Example code:

```
@DateLong
Date startDate;
```

This annotation stores this date as long value. for some reason i have to set zero to this field.

Comment: "stores this date as long value" so why is it a `Date` and not a `long`?

Comment: so can i change as long data type?

Comment: I suggest you try it.

Comment: i just thought. i have to change many places. so can you help me to set zero?

Comment: `Date` is a reference to an object. You can't set it to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT, simplest way to create such date is

```
Date date = new Date(0);
```

When you set your startDate attribute to such value then the graph property will have a long value of `0`